# Proper way to hide place holders in a SharePoint 2007 Master Page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, master-pages, placeholder

I am working on a specialized instance of MOSS for a client where What I am wanting to do is hide elements on the master page. In particular, I want to hide the main top navigation bar, the search functionality and the label that shows up in the upper-left-hand corner that tells you the name of the site you are on. So I made a copy of the default.master, and then in SP Designer I set the visible attributes for the placeholders for these blocks to “false” in the new master file.

I can then assign the master to my normal site collection no problems and it seems to been working like I want it to. But when I go to look at the system pages (i.e. any of the forms or backend stuff), it is still using the old default master. And when I tried to set the System Master Page to my customized master file, my MOSS instance threw a File Not Found error. Then certain parts of the admin area just started failing in that same way (i.e. I would try to go into Site Settings -> Content and Structure and it also would throw a File Not Found error) Then at one point, the whole Site Collection would throw “Unknown Error” and there didn't seem to be a way to recover, short of reverting the state of the VM I am running MOSS in for development purposes.

So I am curious, what is the best way to create a custom master page and then hide elements on that page? I realized that my web cluster didn’t have the proper flag set up to actually show me real ASP error messages, so I am going to change that tonight when I get home and see what SP is really telling me about all of this. I have also read that changing the application.master file is not recommended, but I figured I could get away with making a custom page for the Site and System master pages and not worry about application.master.  I have been reading a bunch of Heather Solomon articles as well as various other things. They all basically say that it’s ok to hide elements on a master page, but not delete them outright as SP will break if you do that. Would it be advisable to use a JS/CSS hack to manually hide elements that way, rather than actually making a new master page?

Answer (score 2):

You create an asp:placeholder with the visible attribute set to false and place the contentplaceholders that are to be hidden in that container, weird I know but it works... as for the system.master you probably would want to make a copy of the system.master that SharePoint uses and then alter that one in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for posting this.  Works like a charm.  I was so afraid because everyone says not to mess with the Application.Master.  All I did was open it with Notepad and add   Visible="false"   (I wanted to hide the topnavigation bar because I have custom tabs that display depending on a user's permissions which are controlled by code in default.master.  But then if a user had to upload a file, upload.aspx uses application.master and all the tabs would be displayed.)

I edited this line only:

```
wssuc:TopNavBar id="IdTopNavBar" runat="server" ShouldUseExtra="true" Visible="false"
```

Works like a charm!

Note that the following pages will also be affected:
Site Settings
View all site content
Workflow settings of a document library
Recycle Bin
Search results